# Gathering observations in the same row if I declare they are matching

Tags: r, reshape

I have some Stata experience but I'm relatively new to R. I have imported this data frame from Stata that contains information on variables (i.e., each observation is for a variable from other datasets): number of categories, format, labels, year of survey etc.) from several Stata datasets. I'm trying to find matching variables with different names to put them in the same row.

My goal is to create a function where all I have to do is to write the names of the matching variables, and R would put them in the same row, in reverse chronological order. So for instance,

```
Variable_Name   Year   Original_Dataset   Label   Distinct_Categories   Continuous
V1              2020   dataset_1         <NA>    10                   TRUE
V2              2018   dataset_2         <NA>    5                    FALSE
V3              2019   dataset_3         <NA>    15                   TRUE
V4              2021   dataset_4         <NA>    8                    FALSE
V5              2022   dataset_5         <NA>    12                   TRUE
V6              2017   dataset_6         <NA>    3                    FALSE
```

Suppose I say that in my survey the variables V6, V3 and V1 are the same, but just spread in different datasets/years. I want to write the names V6, V3, V1 and then R would sort them by reverse chronological order (Year) , and my dataset would look like this:

```
Variable_Name_1   Year_1   Original_Dataset_1   Label_1   Distinct_Categories_1   Continuous_1   Variable_Name_2   Year_2   Original_Dataset_2   Label_2   Distinct_Categories_2   Continuous_2   Variable_Name_3   Year_3   Original_Dataset_3   Label_3   Distinct_Categories_3   Continuous_3
V1                2020     dataset_1           <NA>      10                     TRUE          V3                2019     dataset_3           <NA>      15                     TRUE          V6                2017     dataset_6           <NA>      3                      FALSE
V2                2018     dataset_2           <NA>      5                      FALSE         NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA            NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA
V4                2021     dataset_4           <NA>      8                      FALSE         NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA            NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA
V5                2022     dataset_5           <NA>      12                     TRUE          NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA            NA                NA       NA                  NA        NA                     NA
```

Notice how the wide variables are not named after V3 and V6, but rather have their own numbering (Variable_Name_2, Variable_Name_3...). This is because no matter the observations to be rearranged, no matter their original dataset, I want to interpret the _2 as the "second latest matching variable available".

I don't know if I explained my issue well or if this is doable on Stata. But in any case any help would be appreciated!! I am ready to give more details in case I'm not clear.

Have a very nice day.

I haven't tried anything so far as I'm not aware of any function that would do it and I'm a beginner in R. I hope somebody can help!

Comment: Hi astrori! Welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to learning R! It's a fun language to learn. A couple of questions: 1. how do you know when the variables match? e.g. is it based on the same number of categories, same Year, or something else? 2. This might not mean anything to you right now, but it's generally bad practice to save important information in column names. Doing that makes it hard to use and can lead to headaches down the line. Also it can avoid adding heaps of NAs to your data, as in your example. I'd recommend keeping things in the long format,

Comment: and adding some kind of order column in this example

Comment: I provided a solution, but I'm in agreement with Mark in so far, as its a somewhat poisened chalice. you get what you want, but you might not in the future enjoy drinking it. it goes against my principles as a generally *tidy* developer. for reference see : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Comment: Hi Mark and Nir, thank you for your answers! 

There is no way to automatically know when the variable match. I have to go manually look at every wave of the survey, check the documentation if the variable names are the same, and note possible changes.

Thank you for your comments about data formats. So, in a long format, the problem would then be about assigning a common ID to matching variables, and then sorting the observations accordingly so that within each group, the matching variables are sorted by reverse chronological order ? Am I correct?

Comment: hmm it depends! Are there the same column names across multiple datasets (e.g. is there a V1 for any other year other than 2020, or dataset other than dataset_1?

Comment: No, V1 can exist in a particular year, then disappear from the questionnaire for later waves. 

Similarly the number of datasets for each year is unconsistent over time, so there's no clear-cut rule for this. Which is why I have to do everything manually :(

Comment: are you 'doing it manually' in a consistent, rule based way ? if so you can probably program it away,  it requires you to be explicit about the steps in the process you perform.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)
start_df <- readr::read_delim(
  "Variable_Name Year Original_Dataset Label Distinct_Categories Continuous
V1 2020 dataset_1 <NA> 10 TRUE
V2 2018 dataset_2 <NA> 5 FALSE
V3 2019 dataset_3 <NA> 15 TRUE
V4 2021 dataset_4 <NA> 8 FALSE
V5 2022 dataset_5 <NA> 12 TRUE
V6 2017 dataset_6 <NA> 3 FALSE",
  delim = " "
)



mydfrename <- function(x, y) {
  rename_with(x, \(n)paste0(n, y))
}

myfunc <- function(start_df, v_to_get) {
  (suffixes <- paste0("_", seq_along(v_to_get)))

  (remainder <- start_df |>
    filter(!Variable_Name %in% c(v_to_get)))

  (chunk1 <- start_df |>
    filter(Variable_Name %in% c(v_to_get)) |>
    arrange(desc(Year)) |>
    rowwise() |> group_split() |> set_names(suffixes))


  (chunk_processed <- imap_dfc(chunk1, mydfrename))

  bind_rows(
    chunk_processed,
    mydfrename(remainder, "_1")
  )
}

myfunc(
  start_df = start_df,
  v_to_get = c("V6", "V3", "V1")
)
```

Comment: It's poor form to not provide any descriptions to a complete noobie, and while just creating the desired output manually is one option, it's not at all clear to me that that is the option OP actually wants

Comment: I don't understand your comment about creating the desired output manually ? its functionalised, which means from the user perspective he gets what he asked for in the way that he asked it, by passing a list of variables to match.

Comment: about descriptions, I'm not sure they would add much value. I could write 'this vertically stacks i .e. row binds the rows, next to bind_rows() ; but equally, the noobie, could go away and look up the function calls and learn what they do, and for my money the code is not particularly obfuscated, its laid out rather linearly, and each step can be followed. (though this requires a noob to learn how to step through R code; but I think a lesson on that is out of scope for me to provide.

Comment: should I delete my solution because I havent fully documented it ? because I have some time to spend on testing myself and helping people; but this is not my job so theres a limit to how 'helpful' I can be. if someone else wants to come along and edit my answer to have 'documentation' I wouldnt be aggrieved.

Comment: 1. what *they* asked for, and 2. OP says *Suppose I say that in my survey the variables V6, V3 and V1 are the same*. My interpretation of it was that this was stating an assumption about the underlying data, not necessarily saying that OP had a vector of duplicate columns ready to go in that form, but I might be wrong. That wasn't as important as the second thing; sure adding heaps of comments would be overkill but none is a bit bad you have to admit

Comment: 1) from the OP : `I want to write the names V6, V3, V1 and then R would sort them`

Comment: I admit nothing :)

Comment: if the desired output is anything to go by, OP is asking for something which is suboptimal- it's full of NAs and untidy as heck. While I can understand and empathise with you in wanting to just giving question askers what they want, sometimes they're *complete newbies*, and  it's as important to show them good practices as it is to give them directly what they want. Either they do it now or they come back later complaining when nothing works, and have to unlearn bad habits we helped reinforce

Comment: I actually agree, it hurts my brain that OP wants this, but they self declared having come from a STATA background, and I suppose that implies that they want what they want. I'm all for commenting to them , that purposefully going untidy is ... likely a poor choice, and point them to r4ds or whathave you. But you have already done that in a comment, and the OP can read our discussion here. I dont see that its appropriate to add a lecture to my solution post.

Comment: re: `I want to write the names V6, V3, V1 and then R would sort them`- thank you for sharing that! I somehow overlooked/missed that bit

Comment: re:  *they self declared having come from a STATA background, and I suppose that implies that they want what they want* - I don't think I follow- they have *some* experience, and they're *relatively new* to R. re: *you have already done that in a comment* - sure, I have, (and now you have too)- I don't know about your experience of looking at StackOverflow questions, but I generally look at the answers first, so while the comments are great, if something is important it makes sense to include it in the answer, even if just in passing

Comment: re: *I dont see that its appropriate to add a lecture to my solution post* - I never suggested that, don't be ridiculous

Comment: im never ridiculous, but thanks for giving me lots of attention today.